# Jquery accordion customize click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using [Jquery accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) for accordion. problem is that I want to show and hide conent panel when user click on plus or minus icon but it open all over on header click and also [toggles](http://simontabor.com/labs/toggles/) are not working in chrome and safari in header section and working on content section any help should be apriciated.
[image]
code-

```
<?php
$cs=Yii::app()->clientScript;
$cs->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/jquery.min.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
$cs->registerScriptFile('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
$cs->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/toggles.min.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
$cs->registerCssFile('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
$cs->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/css/themes/toggles-light.css');
$cs->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/css/toggles.css');
```

?>

css-

```
 <style>
.ui-accordion-header {
    background:none;
}
.ui-accordion-content {
    background:none;
}
.iconOpen {
    background:url('<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/img/minus.png') no-repeat !important;
    background-size:46px !important;
    width:46px;
    height:44px;
}
.iconClosed {
    background:url('<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/img/plus.png') no-repeat !important;
    background-size:46px !important;
    width:46px;
    height:44px;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-accordion-header-icon {
    top: 25%;
    left: 0.0em;
    margin-top: -12px;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-icons {
    padding-left: 4.2em;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 26px !important;
}
</style>
```

js-

```
<script>
$(function() {
 var icons = {
         header: "iconClosed",    // custom icon class
         activeHeader: "iconOpen" // custom icon class
     };
$( "#main_accordion" ).accordion({
icons: icons,
collapsible: true,
heightStyle: "content"
});
$('.toggle').toggles({clicker:$('.clickme')});

});
</script>
```

Html:-

```
<div id="main_accordion">
    <h3>R
      <div align="right" style=" margin-top: -16px;">
        <div class="toggle-light">
          <div class="toggle"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </h3>
    <div>
      <p>interface</p>
    </div>
    <h3>F
      <div align="right" style=" margin-top: -16px;">
        <div class="toggle-light">
          <div class="toggle"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </h3>
    <div>
      <p> Feed Back
      <div class="toggle-light">
        <div class="toggle"></div>
      </div>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: check, maybe you missing something. or there is some other jquery function also which are conflicting with your this accordion jquery.
if, it is like that, then use noConflict()

Comment: @wikijames every thing is ok and it is working on ie and Firefox and also no js error with firebug.

Comment: It means now, no problem :) . thats nice

Comment: @wikijames problem with chrome and safari and also restrict click event on only icon not all header part.

Comment: please post a working jsfiddle

Comment: thank you should sure post a working fiddle. then only able to figure out the problem you having.

Comment: @wikijames  http://jsfiddle.net/princefiddle/PKe5X/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To restrict the open/close of the accordion to only the icon you will need to use the `beforeActivate` option and check where the click originated. If it is not from the icon then cancel the activation event.

```
$( "#main_accordion" ).accordion({
    icons: icons,
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content",
    beforeActivate:function(event, ui ){
            var fromIcon = $(event.originalEvent.target).is('.ui-accordion-header > .ui-icon');
            return fromIcon;
        }
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/5Qfwc/

---

**Update** (*for toggles after OP added link to jsfiddle*)

For the sliders, you have an attribute `align="right"` on the container `div`, which isn't a valid attribute for `div` elements.

I just changed the style to be `float:right` and removed the margin and it works fine on all browsers now..

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/PKe5X/1/

Comment: thanks restrict the open/close of the accordion is now working only toggle on chrome and safari is not working in header section.

Comment: @Prince, we will have to see it somewhere runninig to debug .. other wise I cannot suggest anything.. do not know what the toggles plugin does to the html..